# Show Image that Address saved in database like /image/news/frist.jpg

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I load data from database to a listview by MVC Api and one of data to want to show is Image.
Image saved in database like this "\images\NewsImage\Untitled-4.jpg"
Now we have a website that show news with image that  image address only save in database not image.
This is my code to show data in list view 
Title is showing correctly but image did't show

`HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://somedomain.com/api/values/getlastten");

```
    var TProducts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<News>>(response);
    Label header = new Label
    {
        Text = "ten",
        FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
    };

    ListView listView = new ListView
    {
        ItemsSource = TProducts,
        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            // Create views with bindings for displaying each property.
            Label nameLabel = new Label();
            nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");

            Image nImage = new Image();
            nImage.SetBinding (Image.SourceProperty, @"www.mydomain.com/"+"Image");

            Label ViewdLabel = new Label();
            ViewdLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Viewed");
            nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.FontFamilyProperty, "BNazanin.ttf#Nazanin");

            // Return an assembled ViewCell.
            return new ViewCell
            {
                View = new StackLayout
                {
                    Padding = new Thickness(0, 5),
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                    Children =
                        {
                            nImage,
                            new StackLayout
                            {
                                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                                Spacing = 0,
                                Children =
                                {
                                    nameLabel,
                                    ViewdLabel
                                }
                                }
                        }
                }
            };
        })
    };
    listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        News = (News)e.SelectedItem;

      await  Navigation.PushAsync(new NewsDetails(News));
    };
        this.Content = new StackLayout
    {
        Children =
        {
            header,
            listView
        }
    };

}


private void ProductLV_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    News =(News) e.SelectedItem;

    Navigation.PushAsync(new NewsDetails(News));
}`
```

**Update** My model is

```
 public class News
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summery { get; set; }
    public string FullText { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't create a binding like this

```
nImage.SetBinding (Image.SourceProperty, @"www.mydomain.com/"+"Image");
```

instead, create an `ImageURL` property in your model that will return the properly formatted url for the image and bind to that

```
nImage.SetBinding (Image.SourceProperty, "ImageURL");
```

like this

```
public class News
{
    ...

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public string ImageURL { 
      get {
        return "http://www.example.com/" + Image;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks How can I define and fill ImageUrl? also Update my question.

Comment: In database Image address saved same as \News\Image\Untitle.jpg, i do the same as above post, Image not show but when change \ to / in database address of  image it work, how can i change this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks i do like this   public string Image { get ; set; }
        public string ImageURL
        {
            get
            {
                return @"http:/mydomain.com"+Image.Replace( @"\","/");
            }
        }